# CSS3 Transform skew both ways

Tags: css, transform, transformation

I'm trying to reproduce some kind of fake 3d perspective. How can I do a CSS3 Transform, in some way that I can archive this skew effect.

[image]

Comment: You can also just rotate the object along the X axis and make actually look like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/349x9/2111/). [Reference](https://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/).